# Collection of unique puzzles

Tags: discussion

Big part of this site is not discussions about puzzles and not questions about them, but the puzzles themselves, usually presented by people, who knows solution. This make it different from other SE-sites.

There are huge number of good puzzles on this site, there are even more bad, and also there are a lot of puzzles, which are basically different version or combination of other puzzles.

So, for discussion reasons let's try to separate these groups:

1) Good puzzles. There was already a [topic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/what-are-the-features-of-a-well-written-puzzle), which gave a definition to these.
2) Bad puzzles. Well, basically this is the opposite: unclear formulation, simple or straightforward solution, expected result.
3) Plagiarism puzzles. The puzzles, which anyone who knows solution to "good puzzles" can solve. (Note, that i'm talking about puzzles at this site only).
4) All other questions. About puzzle creation, about how many combinations rubiks-cube has, etc.

There are a lot of 2, 3 and 4 types of questions on this site, and they cover good puzzles.
There are voting system, which more or less works for bad puzzle filtration, but not for filtration of groups 3 and 4.
Even if you know the puzzle and what to propose it to the community there is no good way to check if this is not a duplicate: Search string doesn't help, since you can wrap a puzzle into any story and any words. For example, I consider this puzzle good: [Nine gangsters and a gold bar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/nine-gangsters-and-a-gold-bar) , but I wasn't able to find it, so I've posted the same puzzle, but with different story: [Universal pie division](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36643/universal-pie-division), I would delete it, but the system highly discourages me from doing this using ban-from-asking-threat. Result: another plagiarism puzzle.

**HERE COMES MY POINT:**

I feel like huge number of great puzzles are buried at this site and are unreachable for people. So, my point here, is that we need to create a list of **good & unique** puzzles, may be even using formulation not from puzzling-SE - when it is a classical puzzle. I am not sure how to separate one from another, but this will be a waste if we do not try.

Comment: You can always searched for "closed:no" to avoid seeing puzzles that have been closed as duplicates (or closed for another reason). A search like "closed:no is:question votes:5" will turn up what could be considered good and unique puzzles.

Comment: Searching at SE is still (hopefully) improving.  I almost always use network browsers to find anything here based on content. Related (not duplicate...) posts: 
[Should we implement an automated way of highlighting
 quality content?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4974)
$\raise1mu/$
[Should we have a meta-sorted list of
 puzzles here on Meta?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4968)